# Connections of theory of computability and Turing machines to other areas of mathematics

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, soft-question, computer-science

The question is quite straightforward:
Could you point out some reference papers that highlight (in a way that is fairly accessible) the connections between (1) theory of computability, algorithms, and Turing machines and (2) other areas of mathematics.

Comment: Back in August-September 1999 in the [FOM list](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/) there was a fairly lengthy (and at times heated) discussion of "natural examples" in computability theory, which I think began with this [3 August 1999](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/fom/postings/9908/msg00012.html) post by Robert I. Soare. One of the things discussed appears to have been subsequently published by Soare: [*Computability theory and differential geometry*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bsl/1102083758), **Bulletin of Symbolic Logic** 10 #4 (2004), 457-486.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider [Computability and Complexity](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/computability/) :

> [for the] study and classification of which mathematical problems are computable and which are not. In addition, there is an extensive classification of computable problems into computational complexity classes according to how much computation — as a function of the size of the problem instance — is needed to answer that instance.

See e.g. :

- Sanjeev Arora & Boaz Barak, [Computational complexity :  A Modern Approach](https://books.google.it/books?id=nGvI7cOuOOQC&printsec=frontcover) (2009)
- Pavel Pudlak, [Logical Foundations of Mathematics and Computational Complexity](https://books.google.it/books?id=obxDAAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (2013).

And also [Computable Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis) i.e. :

> is the study of mathematical analysis from the perspective of computability theory. It is concerned with the parts of real analysis and functional analysis that can be carried out in a computable manner.

See e.g. :

- Klaus Weihrauch, [Computable Analysis : An Introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=OPolVWVFDJYC&printsec=frontcover) (2000) [and also [here](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/resources/pdf/ica.pdf)].

Comment: $+1$ Thanks. Would you mind specifying what are the prerequisites to understand the books you mentioned (in particular Weihrauch's)?

Comment: @Dal - for CA, start browsing the linked document; you can see what's needed : some set theory and algebra, of course calculus, computability th (Turing or equivalent), notion of algorithms and computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

Linear and Integer Programming utilize these a lot. I read a paper for my IP class showing that there is no algorithm to solve IPs with quadratic constraints. It was proven by a reduction to Hilbert's Tenth Problem, which is unsolvable. The reduction had a standard computability feel to it. Hilbert's Tenth Problem deals with satisfying arbitrary Diophantine equations.

Graph theory and combinatorics are the obvious places where algorithms come into play.

Game theory is really starting to benefit from computer science and algorithms. Algorithmic game theory is a very hot topic with applications to economics and AI. Computability comes up some too: 
http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0198 
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01212014 
http://econpapers.repec.org/paper/fthcambri/153.htm